# Death Counter Help

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need help creating a successful death counter that connects to a scoreboard. I have a detection system already thought out but I can't test to see if it works. Here's my thought process:

1. Players Pvp.
2. When killed, teleport to their 'base' and a point is rewarded as "Deaths."
3. After a player has reached twenty "Deaths," he/she will be teleported to a different location where they can view the other players.

### Redstone workings: (After Death Counter)

A redstone clock will constantly trigger a testfor command block that has:

```
/testfor @a [score={Deaths=20..}]
```

with a comparator monitoring for output to power a command block with:

```
/tp @a {scores=Deaths=20..}] x y z
```

and kill them again so it doesn't keep teleporting them (although I don't know for sure if the comparator will pick up the change and activate more than once).

I'm on console edition so any changes to the commands with syntax are probably subject to change. Try to make it BE friendly, and do not use XP as part of the workings.

Comment: No one likes "wall of text" posts. Please consider organizing your post into paragraphs, lists, and headings. Use code font generously. You can learn more about how to format on the [help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: And what exactly do you want us to do? You've given us a schematic of how you accomplish your task. That's great, but where exactly is the problem with your code? Is something causing an error? From what I see right now, it's not clear.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 As you know about my previous post, I had problems with my initial death counter. I have yet to test anything out because the first step doesn't work. When writing programs, I'm sure you are aware that if one step is incorrect, especially if an early line of code is the culprit. You can't know for sure if there is more bugs. As for my initial code, I had a simple script from researching and neglected to test it until putting together something more complete. This previous command was /scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount. This may work on Java, but not on BE.

Comment: As soon as you posted that comment, I saw the problem, and it's much worse than what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually posted an incorrect answer on your previous solution. It would have worked, but there was a much more sinister problem that is halting your operation.

Look on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#In_Bedrock_Edition) on Scoreboards.

> #### In Bedrock Edition
>
> Currently, `dummy` is the only criterion supported. As such, score can only be changed by commands.

Comment: Yes, that's what I gauged when looking at youtube videos vs. what I saw on PS4. Unfortunately, I might set up a pressure plate connected to a command block that adds a point to their score. However, I don't know the correct command that adds one point to the person. Perhaps /scoreboard players set @p Deaths +1. Please inform.

Comment: @AnonymousRequest You'll use `/scoreboard players add`. See the [Minecraft Wiki article](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard) and look for the command in one of the tables.